# Can vbs create bat file with line from InputBox?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, inputbox

can someone help me? This vbs script create a run.bat but I need in run.bat second line Answer from InputBox on start of vbs script. It is possible?

```
Answer = LCase(InputBox("Your Answer:", ""))
     If Len(Answer) Then
     Dim objFSO, outFile
            Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
            Set outFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("run.bat", True)
    outFile.WriteLine "Your answer is: "
    outFile.WriteLine """Answer"

    outFile.Close

    WScript.Echo "Done."
End If
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, you just need to remove the double quotes from this line:

```vb
outFile.WriteLine """Answer"
```

so that the value of the variable `Answer` is written to the file instead of the string `"Answer`:

```vb
outFile.WriteLine Answer
```

You can even make the answer appear on the same line as the text `Your answer is:` if you generate the output like this:

```vb
outFile.Write "Your answer is: "
outFile.WriteLine Answer
```

or like this:

```vb
outFile.WriteLine "Your answer is: " & Answer
```

Comment: And what abot Answer between text? Like: outFile.WriteLine Your Answer is right ?

Comment: You can concatenate more than two strings in a row: `outFile.WriteLine "Your answer is: " & Answer & " some other text"`.